# Deploying to Azure: "Access to the path ... msshrtmi.dll is denied"

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment

I have a long-standing Azure project that I built in VS2012 against the Azure SDK 2.4, and am attempting to migrate it to VS2015 and Azure 2.7.  I am able to build the project and run it locally, but when I attempt to deploy it fails with the following error:

Access to the path 'C:[user folder]\AppData\Local\Temp[random chars]\roles[solution]\base\x86\msshrtmi.dll' is denied

When I attempt to view that containing folder it doesn't exist... perhaps it is removed after the publish failure?  I've found the msshrtmi.dll within the solution folders, and have tried changing the platform targeting that has been claimed to help other msshrtmi.dll issues, but most of those seem to be fails at build time not publish time.

I've re-built a new Azure solution and imported my web role project and get the same result.  I've never had to delve deep in to the VS configuration/build/deploy world before and am hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception. My resolution was a workaround given to me by the Microsoft Azure Tools team - package or publish on a 64-bit machine. My VM was 32-bit. As soon as I packaged on the 64-bit machine, this error went away and I could publish once again.

The same team members said this issue will be fixed in the Azure 2.7.1 release around the end of August.

Comment: Thanks KVD - Glad to hear it's not just me.  I've reverted to VS 2012 for now and will keep an eye out for the next Azure update.