# Updated to VS 2015, Azure 2.7, publish fails 'Access to path ... denied'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service project with three worker roles. Previously (VS 2013, Azure 2.5) everything published fine. When VS 2015 was available, I installed it on a clean VM and then installed Azure 2.7. I promoted my old solution and I can build and run locally just fine. I can build the cloud service project. But when I try to publish or package, I get the following error and the build fails.

Error:

> Access to the path
>   'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\3xhd2e4m.wlw\roles[rolename]\base\x86\msshrtmi.dll'
>   is denied. C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure
>   Tools\2.7\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets 3003

When I go to Temp - there is no directory corresponding to 3xhd2e4m.wlw.

My resolution attempts so far include:

Removing the worker roles from the solution and trying to publish - fails with same error for the remaining project.
Removed read-only from temp
Tried to set everything to build x64
I really need some help since this blocking deployment and testing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. According to an answer in another post ([Deploying to Azure: "Access to the path ... msshrtmi.dll is denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596327/deploying-to-azure-access-to-the-path-msshrtmi-dll-is-denied/32245477#32245477)), the problem is related with an issue with the Azure SDK 2.7 and will be solved in version 2.7.1, supposed to be released shortly.

The problem occurs only when you try to publish from a 32-bit machine. Changing to a 64-bit machine should work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer a specific solution as I haven't taken the plunge and upgraded to VS2015 yet, however I imagine this has something to do with the project file for the Worker Role's Cloud Service.

So, two options come to mind:

1. Create a new blank Worker Role Project with a single boilerplate Worker Role and check that it publishes/packages correctly. This will confirm whether this functionality works in VS2015 with Azure SDK 2.6.
2. If (1) works, consider adding one of your existing Worker Role Projects to the blank Worker Role Project in (1) and try the publish/package process again.

I find it hard to believe that the chaps at Microsoft have tried the upgrade path from v2.5 -> v2.6 of the SDK for Worker Roles... I've checked the v2.6 Release Notes and there doesn't appear to be any breaking changes related to this issue: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-2_6/

Comment: Appreciate the attempt to assist, but I tried option #1 and the error still persists. I've additionally started a completely clean solution for a cloud service project with a web role and worker role and the issue again persists.

Comment: You probably need to raise a defect with Microsoft then. Bummer.

Comment: Thanks, Nick ... They're on it now.

Answer (score 0):

I just got hit with this same issue and lost a few brain cells from it.

I have a defined directory in my ServiceDefinition.csdef that contains all the files I'm trying to copy out during my cloud service publish for my startup tasks, and I ended up including some .dll files as well.  I was getting the same error as the OP of this question and after some time found out that I just couldn't include the *.dll files in my SourceDirectory path.  I was able to include .cmd files just fine, but .dll and .config's were no good.

It wasn't good enough to exclude them from my project either, just the fact that the files were in that directory was enough to make VS yell at me.

For now I've just put all the offending files in a zip and I'm sending the zip file in my deployment, so it's a workaround, but was a painful one until I figured this much out.

Hope this helps..